# Using real HTTP error code in wicket

Tags: wicket, portlet

I need to respond with an error code. When I am using `AbortWithHttpStatusException` my response is like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
portlet.http-status-code: 507
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2012 09:49:52 GMT
```

which is interpreted by browser (firefox at least) as 200 OK, which seems ok, since there is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` at the beginning. How can I force wicket to return other http code?

I am using wicket 1.4.18

Comment: Doesn't `AbortWithHttpStatusException` take an `int` parameter?

Comment: @jbrookover yes, it does. I've set it to 507 which resulted in `portlet.http-status-code: 507` part, but it's not what I wanted to achieve

Comment: Are you using this in a portlet container (the `portlet.http-status-code` attribute looks like a `PortletResponse` special case) ?

Comment: @CedricGatay Yes, I'm using liferay as a container. For now I have added `httpResponse.setStatus(statusCode);` in `WicketResponseState`, and it seems to be working well, but I don't quite like the fact that I had to override wicket class...

Comment: @AdamPierzchała the thing is it is the portlet container that is assumed to handle your status code, you should not bypass it

Comment: @CedricGatay ok, but why? If I decide that I want to use specific http code because of some situation, why would it be ok that portlet container ignores it?

Comment: The portlet container always wraps the response. I think there is some way to serve dynamic resources with the Portlet API 2.0, which could be used to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same **customize HTTP Status Code (e.g. 404 Not Found) in Wicket** functionality too (not with portlet) and `configureResponse()` works beautifully:

```
package org.soluvas.web.bootstrap;

import org.apache.wicket.request.http.WebResponse;

/**
 * @author atang
 *
 */
public class PageNotFound extends BootstrapPage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PageNotFound() {
        super();
//      add(new Page404());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureResponse(WebResponse response) {
        super.configureResponse(response);
        response.setStatus(404);
    }

}
```

Taken from https://github.com/soluvas/soluvas-web project.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however I remember that the problem was because it was portlet. And anyway, I'm not in this project anymore, so I can't try it.